# python error when compiling app that uses ahk

Tags: python, pyinstaller, autohotkey

I use AHK in my app, and when I compile the app with pyinstaller and click on the resulting .exe file: this error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "up.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "ahk\keyboard.py", line 94, in key_state
  File "ahk\keyboard.py", line 85, in _key_state
  File "ahk\script.py", line 130, in render_template
  File "jinja2\environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
  File "jinja2\environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
  File "jinja2\loaders.py", line 126, in load
  File "jinja2\loaders.py", line 218, in get_source
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: keyboard/key_state.ahk
```

I copied the templates folder from the autohotkey subdirectory to the project folder, But that doesn't solv my problem.
my code:

```
import time
from ahk import AHK
a=AHK()
press=False
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if a.key_state("f11")==True:
        press=not press
    if press == True:
        a.key_press("up")
```

Comment: recheck whither file `keyboard/key_state.ahk` is avilable in the `template` forlder or its missing?

Comment: import time
from ahk import AHK
a=AHK()
press=False
while not press:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if a.key_state("f11")==True:
        press=not press
    else:
        press = True
        a.key_press("up")

Comment: @Muhammad Zakaria
Yes it exists.

Comment: @toyota Supra
not solv.

Comment: What if you replace this press=not press to  ahk.key_wait("f11", timeout=3

Comment: @toyota Supra
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem and probably everyone who converts to exe will face the same problem --add-data you need to specify, actually that's the reason for the error, here's the code I used for myself, you can edit it

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --add-data "C:\Users\fatih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\ahk;ahk" mc.py
```